# How do I create new object after manipulation

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I have a JavaScript object like the following below availability and reserved, here I need to subtract quantity value from availability.

```
var availability = {"bike":10,"cycle":3,"car":1};

var reserved ={"cycle":1,"bike":10}
```

how should I get this response as below?

```
response = {"bike":0,"cycle":2,"car":1};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through each key-value pair and subtract quantity in `availability` with the corresponding key in `reserved`. Then create your result object using `Object.fromEntries()`.

```js
const availability = { "bike" : 10, "cycle" : 3, "car" : 1 },
      reserved ={ "cycle": 1,"bike": 10 },
      result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(availability).map(([key, value]) => [key, value - (reserved[key] ?? 0)]));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you... can i use like thi below       const availability = { "bike" : 10, "cycle" : 3, "car" : 1 },
      reserved ={ "cycle": 1,"bike": 10 },
      availability = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(availability).map(([key, value]) => [key, value - (reserved[key] ?? 0)]));       console.log(availability );

Comment: You can declare `availability` as let variable and then assign `availability = result` before `console.log()`. Ex - let availability = { "bike" : 10, "cycle" : 3, "car" : 1 }, 
     reserved ={ "cycle": 1,"bike": 10 }, 
     result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(availability).map(([key, value]) => [key, value - (reserved[key] ?? 0)])); 
     availability = result;
     console.log(availability);

Answer (score 1):

Why not a simple for loop.

```js
var availability = { bike: 10, cycle: 3, car: 1 };

var reserved = { cycle: 1, bike: 10 };
let response = {};
for (let key in availability) {
  if (reserved[key]) {
    response[key] = availability[key] - reserved[key];
  } else {
    response[key] = availability[key];
  }
}

console.log(response);
```

Output:

```
{ bike: 0, cycle: 2, car: 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to solve this, but I recommend using `reduce()`.

```js
var availibilty = {
  "bike": 10,
  "cycle": 3,
  "car": 1
};

var reserved = {
  "cycle": 1,
  "bike": 10
}

function calc(a, b) {
  const answer = Object.keys(a).reduce((acc, key) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [key]: a[key] - (b[key] || 0)
    }
  }, {});
  console.log(answer);
}

calc(availibilty, reserved);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the `Object. keys()` of one object you provided and subtract the other using reduce() method.

```
var availibilty = {"bike":10,"cycle":3,"car":1};
var reserved ={"cycle":1,"bike":10}


let response = Object.keys(availibilty).reduce((x, y) => {
    x[k] = availibilty[y] - reserved[y];
    return x;
}, {});

console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find `Array.reduce` implementation.

***Logic***

- Loop through keys of `availability` object.
- Find the values of each keys from `reserved` object.
- Store the difference as the value for same key in the `accumulator` array.

```js
var availability = { "bike": 10, "cycle": 3, "car": 1 };
var reserved = { "cycle": 1, "bike": 10 };
const response = Object.keys(availability).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = availability[curr] - (reserved[curr] || 0);
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(response);
```